# Unable to destroy resource pool units

Tags: anylogic

I am working on creating a manufacturing simulation which has multiple shifts of operators throughout the day. Part of the requirements have operators coming on shift and going off shift. When they go off shift, I need to destroy the operator instance so that they disappear from view. Given the possibility of having more complex schedules (some shifts being offset by only a couple of hours), I would like to avoid having a timed event to ensure that new units are created at the beginning of each shift, thus making the animation perform correctly no matter what scale I run my model at.

I have tried using custom resource tasks with a sink and resource end task. I have also tried an enter block with sink block. Neither of those options worked either due to an error (when using sink), or no action occurring (when calling resource task end). I have also tried dynamically reducing the resource pool capacity using the `ResourcePool.setCapacity()` function but run into concurrency issues with idle units.

What I hope to be able to do is create units at the beginning of the shift, and then destroy the same units when the end of their shift occurs. Any help or advice is greatly appreciated.

FYI: I am using AnyLogic 8.4

Comment: Are you using the schedule object to define your shifts? You can do elegantly and set the resource pool to destroy units on shift end...

Comment: I am using the schedule and have tried both integer schedules as well as on/off. I wonder if I am not configuring the resource pool correctly to execute the end of shift. The couple variations of settings that I've tried don't seem to be able to match the behavior you described which is what I am hoping to do. Do you have a screen shot of how the schedule and resource pool should be set up to enable that type of activity? Thanks for the help!